# Baking a tall cake in a regular pan

Tags: baking

I need to make a thick one layer cake (3-4") but I don't have a pan that deep.  Can I use parchment to add height?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you can do this like:
[image]

...though I would recommend multiple layers around.

---

That said, why is it that you "need" to do it this way rather than in layers? The actual baking of an 'extra thick' cake is likely to leave with cake that is over done at the edges and under done in the center.

Comment: ... and probably very domed. +1

Comment: Thanks!  This is what I was thinking of - hubby fixed the issue though when he found a 10" Calphalon loaf pan at the 2nd hand store.  Plenty deep!

 I am making a Batman cake, with the "bat signal" inside it.  So I will make a sheet cake, about 1" thick, use a cookie cutter to cut out the bat.  Then freeze the 10 or so bats, then put some batter at the bottom of the pan, lay in the bats and then surround them with more raw batter. Bake the whole thing - cut it open to see the bat! Like this:  https://sweetandsavorymeals.com/easy-surprise-inside-batman-cake/

Thanks so much for your help!